# I can't get libvips to compile on heroku

Tags: heroku, poppler, vips

I have spent days trying to get the outdated libvips buildpacks working on Heroku. I finally got https://github.com/wwarne/heroku-buildpack-vips to work, but it doesn't seem to have been compiled with libpoppler, so I don't have pdf support which I need. I have tried repeatedly to run the build.sh file, but I have not been successful.

Does anyone know of a way to get libvips installed on heroku with poppler pdf support without adding 200mb to my slug by using apt-get install?

Comment: poppler is GPL and libvips links directly to the library, so many people avoid including it in their binaries. libvips can use pdfium as well, which has a much more liberal licence, but it's significantly harder to build. Sorry, not a very helpful comment.

Comment: This was actually very helpful. I don't have much experience with GPL licensing, so I didn't realize that any project using a GPL library must itself be GPL! I'm working on trying to get pdfium built, thanks.

Comment: Thing to build PDFium, in case anyone else needs it: https://github.com/jcupitt/docker-builds/tree/master/pdfium it really is horribly complicated.